# What is the most effective defence strategy in Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I've tried a few methods but I usually lose, even though I've upgraded my defence towers and walls quite a bit, while I see other people with worse towers and walls doing better at defending their base than me. My town hall is level 5 right now.

It looks like most of the high level players use a diamond shaped base structure, with the towers evenly distributed, and every few buildings with their own surrounding wall. But what I don't understand is how I should determine what defensive tower goes where.

Really, what I want to know is how I should determine how to distribute my defensive towers. If I don't have enough walls or defenses I can easily improvise, but how do I set up my base for max efficiency?

For clarification, I'm not asking for someone to put together a base for me to copy. I just want to know what kind of base design in general works best. I'd also like to know where bombs and spring traps are most effectively placed, because I can never find a good spot.

Comment: Defending Loot or Trophies?

Comment: I've never played Clash of Clans, but from what I've gathered just by reading on this site is that it probably depends on your Town Hall level. As such, this question seems to be a bit broad-scoped, but again, I do not know this for certain thus I will not vote to close at this time. If there is any information you can add to the question to narrow it down, that would probably be helpful :)

Comment: @ModDL Defending Trophies primarily, but defending loot is nice as a side benefit.

Comment: @Robotnik You are correct, it does depend on level to a point, but I want to know what the best over all strategy in defending my base should be. Should I strive to get everything isolated in its own walls, should I keep side distractions in the corners, etc. I updated the question to clarify it better. Thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'best' defense. Making a particular layout will make your base defend against one type of attack, but less effective against another type of attack and this applies for all town hall levels. A few things that help defense is to have non symmetrical bases, and try to force the hand of the attacker in coming in from a particular side. If you can successfully control that, you can easily move traps more appropriately.

Comment: @Jerry Ok, this is very helpful, could you add it as an answer? I'd also enjoy if you added a few methods that are used to make opponents attack in a certain way. The only two that I could think of would be putting weaker walls in a certain area that you want them to attack, or placing resources where you want them to attack. Are there any others? Again, I think what you wrote would be very good as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Jerry said, there is no "best defense", and frankly at th5 you are fairly low on the totem pole as far as power goes, so there isn't a lot you can do to protect your base. However if you are looking to try and build a better base, consider reading through these tutorials. http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Flammy's_Strategy_Guides
A few key points are understanding how troop ai's work, and building your base in such a way that takes advantage of it, don't double up on walls, don't try to cram everything inside of your walls, and don't spread your defenses out too much. What's nice about this is under his base-defense-basics page, he has a video on building a th5 base from start to finish.

One thing I would suggest for lower level th's in general is to not worry about trophies too much. I am a mid level th9 and have never had my th inside my walls in main base. put it in the corner and hope someone attacks it and not your base. if they do you lose 1000 elixir and gold, and you get a nice 12 hour shield. everything really just comes down to personal preference and trial and error.

Note that as of the 2015 winter update, which is at the time of this edit not yet released, TH snipes will **no** longer provide the defender with a shield and your TH will store more than 1000 elixir and gold, equivalent to 1 gold storage, 1 elixir storage, and 25% of your dark elixir.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that defense in Clash of Clans relies heavily on surprising your opponent. A good attacker that knows where your traps are is going to be able to destroy your base, this is especially true at lower town hall levels, so try and organize your base in a way that could trip up the attacker.

For example, you could try putting your traps in unexpected positions, or all of your traps on one side of the base. If the attacker attacks from that side he is in for a world of hurt and your base has a much better chance of defending! NOTE: I'm not saying this is always correct or better way to set up a base, just an idea of something you could implement to trip up an attacker.